# Express polynomial as sum of two lower-degree polynomials, modulo another

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, polynomials, computer-algebra

Suppose I have a polynomial $p(x)$, and a "modulus" polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $d$.  I want to find two polynomials $r_1(x),r_2(x)$ of degree $\le d_1,d_2$ such that
$$p(x) \equiv r_1(x) x^t + r_2(x) \pmod{q(x)}$$
Assume $d_1+d_2= d$, and that we are working over some finite field.

Given $p(x),q(x),d,d_1,d_2,t$, is there an algorithm to find $r_1(x),r_2(x)$ that meets the conditions above (if any exist)?

In the special case where $t=d_2$, this is handled by reducing $p(x)$ mod $q(x)$, but I'm wondering if there is an efficient algorithm for the more general case.  One algorithm is to express the coefficients of $r_1(x),r_2(x)$ as unknowns, write down $n$ linear equations in terms of these $d_1+d_2$ unknowns, and then solve the resulting linear system; this will take $O(d^3)$ time.  Is there a more direct solution exploiting that these are polynomials, perhaps one achieving faster performance, such as $O(d)$ time?

Comment: Well, FFT gives you are way to do that division faster than solving the system of equations. See [here](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/polydivide.pdf#page=2).

Comment: @plop, yeah, I already know you can use FFT for division, and you can use division to solve the case $t=d_2$ efficiently, but that's not my question - my question is whether you can solve the general case (where $t>d_2$) efficiently.  Do you have a way to do that with FFT?  I currently can't see how to do that.

Comment: Well, some cases there will be no solutions forced by the relations between the degrees $d_1,d_2,t,d$ and the degree $s$ of the remainder of $p$ modulo $q$. For example, if $d>d_1+t>d_2$,  and $d_1+t>s$, then we can't have such $r_1$ of degree $d_1$. Before thinking further, let me ask, because the conditions $d_1+d_2\leq d$ and $r_1,r_2$ having degree exactly $d_1,d_2$ look bizarre. Is that really what you want? You don't want $r_1,r_2$ of degree at most $d_1,d_2$, or do you?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that essentially you want to find a representation of $p(x)$ in basis $(1,\ldots,x^{d_2}, \ x^{t}, \ldots, x^{t + d_1}, q(x), x q(x), x^2 q(x), \ldots)$?

Comment: @plop, Sorry.  you're right.  I really want them to have degree at most $d_1,d_2$.  Also, let's assume $d_1+d_2=d$, for simplicity.  I edited the question.

Comment: @Dmitry, yup, exactly!  I'm hoping that the polynomial-based structure will allow a more efficient solution than solving a system of linear equations.

Comment: Since the only problem is getting zero for $x^{d_2 + 1}, \ldots, x^t$, you only need to consider their coefficients and you can get dependence on $t-d_2$ instead of $d$. Something like $O(d (t - d_2))^2$, maybe even better.